# React Styled Component any type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

## Background

- I'm creating a React UI Library.
- I'm using TS: 5.x, React: 18.x, Styled-Component: 5.x versions.

## Problem Situation

After deploying the UI Library to the npm registry, I did `yarn add my-custom-ui-library` in another test project and imported the component to use it. For the regular component, TS catches the type of the props well, but the styled-component comes out as any.

Here's what FlexBox.d.ts looks like.

```js
/// <reference types="react" />
export interface FlexBoxProps {
    direction?: React.CSSProperties['flexDirection'];
    justify?: React.CSSProperties['justifyContent'];
    align?: React.CSSProperties['alignItems'];
    gap?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
} declare const FlexBox: import("styled-components").StyledComponent<"div", any, FlexBoxProps, never>;
export default FlexBox;
```

Here, if you hover over the `import("styled-components").StyledComponent` part, you will see that it is of type `any`.

In use, the

`<FlexBox>`, you can use it, but TS will not recognize the props.

On the other hand, the regular non-styled-component Chip.d.ts catches the type of the props well.

```js
/// <reference types="react" />
import { ButtonVariant } from '../Button/types';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
interface ChipProps extends React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof motion.div> {
    variant?: ButtonVariant;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}
declare function Chip({ variant, children, ...props }: ChipProps): import("react/jsx-runtime").JSX.Element;
export default Chip;
```

`<Chip variant="...">TEST CHIP</Chip>`

And this is FlexBox.tsx code.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export interface FlexBoxProps {
  direction?: React.CSSProperties['flexDirection'];
  justify?: React.CSSProperties['justifyContent'];
  align?: React.CSSProperties['alignItems'];
  gap?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
}

const GAP: Record<Required<FlexBoxProps>['gap'], `${number}px`> = {
  small: '12px',
  medium: '24px',
  large: '36px'
};

const FlexBox = styled.div<FlexBoxProps>`
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: ${({ direction }) => direction || 'column'};
  justify-content: ${({ justify }) => justify || 'initial'};
  align-items: ${({ align }) => align || 'initial'};
  gap: ${({ gap }) => (gap ? GAP[gap] : 'initial')};
`;

export default FlexBox;
```

What do we need to do to make Typescript recognize the props in the FlexBox?

Should I do something is tsconfig.json of my UI Component Library Project?

----- EDITED -----
I did install `@types/styled-components` to my test project.
And Now it works!
Does this mean that I should add `@types/styled-components` as required dependency?
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I added "@types/styled-components" as peerDependencies.

And re-deploy, now it works well.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26"
},
```

Thanks.